# Visibility indicators keyboard shortcut

Tags: coderush

I have recently begun using coderush.
One thing that annoys me is that the templates almost always expand to private, where as I often want them to be public.

Since I use the keyboard alot, I would like to know if there is a keyboard shortcut in CR for changing the access modifiers similar to clicking on the visibility indicators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are **Alt+Up** and **Alt+Down** shortcuts to cycle through the legal visibility modifiers of an active member. This feature is called [Scope Cycle](http://www.skorkin.com/2010/11/coding-helpers-scope-cycle/). When the editor caret is somewhere inside a member (e.g. property, method, class, etc), the shortcuts will change its visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst in a method, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> to cycle the visibility of the method.

For example: Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> within a method that is **private**, to change it's visibility to **public**

---

Additionally you can change the default visibility of any member type, via the options screen <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

This options page you'll need is **Editor\Code Style\Scope** page.

You can allocate a different default visibility to any of [**Fields**, **Constants**, **Methods**, **Properties**, **Events**, **Types** or **Nested Types**]

---

If you have any other questions, feel free to post them here on stackoverflow.com or to contact me more directly.

I can be reached @ **roryb@devexpress.com**, or on twitter as **[@Rorybecker](http://twitter.com/rorybecker)**. you can also simply mention CodeRush in your tweet and we will surely pick it up and answer your query as quickly as possible.

Comment: Hi Rory, I'm trying to make sense of this and having trouble getting this to work with the smart constructor (cc template).  It always creates a constructor with a `public` access modifier.  I'd like to change the default, but that's not one of the options under Editor\Code Style\Scope.  Any thoughts?

Comment: A few questions if I may.... Which version number of CodeRush are you running? Also are you running CRR (CodeRush for Roslyn) or CRC (CodeRush classic)? Finally: Which version of Studio are you running?

Comment: Hey Rory. Sorry for the delayed response. You are correct. There is no option to alter the default visibility of the Smart Constructor. However you should stilll be able to use the Alt+Up, Alt+Down shortcuts to alter the visibility after the expansion. If this is not working then I suggest you file something in our support center. http://devexpress.com/sc